# How to add request header to BayeuxClient

Tags: cometd, request-headers, bayeux

```
  String url = "some_url";
  HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
  httpClient.start();
  Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  LongPollingTransport transport = new LongPollingTransport(options, httpClient);
  BayeuxClient client = new BayeuxClient(url, transport);
  client.getChannel(Channel.META_HANDSHAKE).addListener(new ClientSessionChannel.MessageListener() {
     public void onMessage(ClientSessionChannel channel, Message message) {
         System.out.println(message);
     }
  });
  client.handshake();
```

Getting

```
{"failure":{"exception":"org.cometd.common.TransportException: {httpCode=403}","message":{"supportedConnectionTypes":["long-polling"],"channel":"/meta/handshake","id":"2","version":"1.0"},"httpCode":403,"connectionType":"long-polling"},"channel":"/meta/handshake","id":"2","subscription":null,"successful":false}
```

So my first guess is to add authorization header. How can I do that?
Jetty 9 is used for both the server and the client code libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at [this test case](https://github.com/cometd/cometd/blob/3.0.9/cometd-java/cometd-java-client/src/test/java/org/cometd/client/HandshakeWithAuthenticationTest.java) that shows how to do it.

Comment: I want to this in .NET. Do you have any example? Maybe something missing or wrong about Authorization. I asked a question here can you please check it out?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441782/cannot-receive-cometd-messages-on-net